# MOQ .NET 4.5 Issue with Test-Code

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Has anyone else had any problems or issues trying to use the Moq dll & provided files from the 2011 distribution of the tool in a .NET 4.5 environment?  I am working with a large set of test-code that uses Moq within many of its tests, and the component-code just moved to .NET 4.5 (and Visual Studio 2012 / SQL server 2012.  If anyone has any info, or if this works for you without any troubles please let me know!  Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Our project has a lot of tests using Moq, and is a .NET 4.5 project. Don't remember the Moq version right now, but probably the newest one. Your question is really vague and unconcrete.

Comment: Asking if anyone has had any problems, without being concrete on what kind problems you have yourself, is vague. You also ask us to tell you if it works for us, and in my comment I informed you that it does work for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not remember if I faced any difficulties when I moved my code to NET 4.5. Now everything works well in my project.

I suggest you use [**NuGet**](http://www.nuget.org/) package manager to add any 3rd party libraries to all your projects.

Last version of [***Moq: an enjoyable mocking library 4.1.1311.615***](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) was published on Monday, November 18 2013.